# why is "わたしはお客様に満足してもらう" not "わたしはお客様に満足してあげる"

Tags: giving-and-receiving

お客様に満足してもらう？ kind of strange to think.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13607/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44169/9831

Comment: お客様に満足させてあげる is a meaningful phrase, though not the mirror image of してもらう.

Answer (score 5):

お客様に満足してもらう is not strange at all, and this is a very simple example of ～てもらう. Please check the [grammar pattern of ～てもらう](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n4-grammar-%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%86-te-morau/). Also note the transitivity; 満足する is "to be satisfied" and 満足させる is "to satisfy."

お客様に満足してもらう literally means "to have customers be satisfied", or more naturally, "to satisfy customers (by doing something)."

お客様に満足してあげる is grammatical but means something very strange, "I will be satisfied as a favor to my customers."

Comment: Presumably it's the "doing something for the benefit of another" nuance that comes with てあげる. Phrased another way, "I will be satisfied as a favor to my customers," it's just as strange.

Answer (score 0):

お客様に満足してもらう(お客様に満足していただく）＝お客様を満足させてあげる（お客様を満足させて差し上げる）